# remmina saved VNC connections fail to open

Tags: vnc, remmina

I can't get remmina to do VNC with a saved profile. It always works if I type everything in manually, but if I try to use a profile, it fails. No error or anything. The window just opens and then closes.

Profile settings:

```
Protocol: Remmina VNC Plugin
Server: IP I'm connecting to
Username: my user
Password: my pass
```

everything else is default.

Answer (score 0):

try to change colour depth from 8bpp to 32bpp